# VSCode: Replace spaces with underscores in expanded variables values

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

I'm trying to configure a VSCode with a [CMake Tools plugin](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.cmake-tools) to have out-of-source builds and separate build directory for each build variant (toolchain + Debug/Release).

My current config looks something like this:

```
"cmake.buildDirectory": "${workspaceFolder}/../.builds/${workspaceRootFolderName}_${buildKit}_${buildType}"
```

BUT often times toolchain name contains a space: see [`${buildKit}`](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/develop/docs/cmake-settings.md#variable-substitution), and spaces in paths are bad for most of the tools, and I have a build failing because of that.

SO is there a way to have something similar in settings but with all spaces from any of the variables replaced with underscores? Some macro or anything that does such replacements?

Comment: don't use spaces in any of those places, name the kit without spaces and so the directory and filenames

Comment: The kit is named automatically by CMake tools plugin.